# QPushbutton with scc style

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Here is the image I want to show because will be hard to explain what I want without it
[image]

and here is button code:

```
self.exitBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
self.exitBtn.setGeometry(505, 395, 80, 80)
self.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.closeApp)
self.exitBtn.setStyleSheet('background: #000;  color: #FF7E00')
self.exitBtn.setIcon(icon)
self.exitBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(self.exitBtn.width(), self.exitBtn.height()))
```

As you can see around button there is some dotted border, possible to remove this 'border'? I tried set up style sheet 'border: 0px' but it does not help. I guess this is something with focus?

Comment: if it really uses all HTML/CSS rules then maybe ask HTML/CSS developers: [Remove Dotted Link Borders](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-dotted-link-borders/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is to do:

```
self.exitBtn.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

PS:

It would be possible to do this in a cleaner way by subclassing `QProxyStyle` and reimplementing `drawPrimitive`. However, `QProxyStyle` is only available in PyQt5.